# Cover a polygon with least amount of parallelograms

Tags: computational-geometry, polygon

I am solving the task that is as follows:

**Input:** a polygon. Can be any kind of polygon without self intersections. Can be a non-convex and with holes inside.

**Goal:** to cover it with 2 (at least) or more parallelograms that together are equal to or contain the whole polygon. The following criteria should be met:

- There is no point of the polygon that lies beyond parallelograms.
- The number of the parallelograms should be the least possible. I.e. we want to find largest parallelograms that cover the polygon.
- These parallelograms must not intersect within the polygon.

**Question:** Is this task solved and if it is solved - how? I am looking for a direction where to start with and what related algorithms/theory to learn.

Comment: When you say *"cover it with 2 (at least)"* and *"The amount of the parallelograms should be the least possible and the square of the parallelograms should be the least possible"* which takes priority? If the former, then surely it must always be 2 parallelograms?

Further, do any of the sides have to be aligned with a major axis or can they be entirely arbitrary?

Comment: @SimonF thanks! Edited question. what is "major axis"? Can you expand?

Comment: By "major axis" I just meant do you want to constrain all the parallelograms so that 2 sides are always horizontal (or vertical)? I was just wondering if you were trying to do, say, some kind of conservative rasterisation. (Also quite a few polygon triangulation algorithms first divide the data into trapeziums (*for those in USA, "trapezoids"* :-/ ) with horizontal  top and bottom edges. I was just thinking maybe you wanted something similar)

Comment: @SimonF I understood that I myself need to know more about the task so I could specify it better. I am going to understand the thing deeper, draw some images of input polygon and desired output and will come back.